# how to substitute the beginning of file names in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, shell

Under my folder, there are a lot of files all starting with "abcd", like "abcd****".

What I am going to do is change all the files names replacing "abcd" by "xyz".

How to use shell command like "find" "sed" to do this?

Comment: Do you need to match files in nested directories, or just files in the current directory?

Comment: Do you have the `rename` command? It's pretty good for this kind of thing.

Comment: @TomFenech: `rename` is a Linux thing - OS X doesn't have it.

Comment: only under current folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a combination of `ls`, `sed` and `xargs` you could use:

```
ls * | sed -e 'p;s!^abcd!xyz!' | xargs -n2 mv
```

**Result:**

```
abcd.png → xyz.png
```

<sub>* *to do a dry-run first, replace **mv** at the end with **echo***</sub>

Answer (score 2):

A simple method would be something like this:

```
for i in abcd*; do mv "$i" "xyz${i#abcd}"; done
```

Comment: Don't forget to quote your variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in abcd*; do mv "$f" "$(echo "$f" | sed 's/^abcd/xyz/g')"; done
```

Comment: Don't forget to quote your variables.

Comment: Ah, yes. I keep forgetting to do that with shell scripts. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: Since you're anchoring to the start of the line, there's not much sense in using the `g` modifier to sed.

Comment: That's force of habit, plus the approach I use with languages where my grasp is a little shaky: "Copy and paste, adjust to taste." I just neglected the "adjust" part.